# moodle - database connection failed when running sync.php script

Tags: moodle

I am setting up a moodle plugin for enrolment from an external database based on instruction in https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/External_database_enrolment. I was successful in setting up a similar plugin for authentication from an external database. But I am having a problem with a plugin for enrolment from the external database. When I test the plugin settings it is successful as shown below https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdrqG.png

But When I run php sync.php I got

Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

My moodle version is 3.9.1 and I am using Mac OS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest to put your moodle in debug mode - in this way you will have more information. (site admin -> development -> debugging - then set "debug messages" to developer and "display debug messages" to checked)

Comment: @Yedidia I did that, but yet I can't see any bug Message in the front end. How can I check it from the server log? I am using MAMP. Thank you.

Comment: @Yedidia I am having the following error message:

 A required parameter (task) was missing

More information about this error

×Debug info:
Error code: missingparam
×Stack trace:
line 498 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 562 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to print_error()
line 44 of /admin/tool/task/schedule_task.php: call to required_param()

Comment: @Yedidia. Thank you for your respond. I have solved the problem. Moodle 3.9.1 does not support php 7.4.2 which is the default selected under preferences of MAMP. To change it go to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php you will see all the available versions of php. Rename the versions you don't need by adding underscore "_" to the names. Then quit your MAMP.  Open MAMP again and goto preferences to select the php version 7.2.22. I hope this will be helpful to others.

Comment: According to https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_and_PHP moodle do support php7.4 and I'm running 3.9 with 7.4..
Seems that your plugin do not.

Answer (score 0):

First, turn on debug, to get errors.

Finally found that the problem was, the plugin do not work with PHP7.4 (while Moodle do).

Fixed by downgrading PHP to 7.2